# Reliability of a system with non-independent parallel components

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reliability

Consider a system $Z$ that consists of two components $X$ and $Y$, whose failure rates per time unit are $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$ respectively.

Assume that if $X$ fails, then the failure rate of $Y$ doubles.
What is the probability density function of the time to failure of the overall system $Z$?

What I could gather so far is the following:

The failure probability of the single components can be modelled as
$$ F_X(t) = 1-e^{-\lambda_X t} \text{ and } F_Y(t) = 1-e^{-\lambda_Y t},$$
where
$$ F_X(t) = \int_0^t f_X(t) dt, f_X(t) = \lambda_X e^{-\lambda_X t} $$ (and the same for Y) is the cumulative density function of an exponential distribution.

Since the two components that make up the system are not independent, the reliability of the system, defined as $R(t) = 1-F(t)$, should begiven by
$$ R(t) = 1-F(t) =  1 - F_X(t) \cdot F_{Y|X}(t).$$

How can one determined the conditioned cdf $F_{Y|X}(t)$?

Comment: when Y fails at first, the failure rate of X will stay the same, right?

Comment: Right, the failure of Y does not impact $\lambda_X$

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

Clues from simulation of a million such systems:
Let $\lambda_x = 2; \lambda_y = 3.$

Then $P(X < Y) = 2/5 = 0.4.$

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rexp(m,2); y = rexp(m,3);  yy = rexp(m,6)
v = pmin(x,y); w = pmax(x,y)
mean(x < y);  mean(x == v)
[1] 0.400608
[1] 0.400608
```

Then, by the no-memory property, the total lifetime of the system is $T$ as shown below.

```
t = 0.4*(v + yy) + 0.6*w
summary(t)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.003752 0.280261 0.450555 0.526562 0.689709 4.661313 

hist(t, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="System Lifetime")
```

[image]

*Notes:* The CDFs of the minimum (exponential) and maximum (not exponential) are easily
obtained, and their PDFs from them. The density
of the [sum of two exponentials with different
rates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412849/does-the-sum-of-two-independent-exponentially-distributed-random-variables-with) is nontrivial. But then the PDF of the
[mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BruceET ! Do you have a reference that treats this problem analytically?

Comment: I intended this more as an outline than a detailed analytical solution because it's a multi-part project. // The first task is to establish the probability 0.4 by finding the distribution of the difference between two exponential distributions with differing rates. Next you can use the CDF method to find that the minimum of exponentials is again exponential with the sum of the rates; also to find that the maximum is not exponential. (Differentiate the CDF to get the PDF.) Finally, the link at the end shows how to get the dist'n of the sum of the min and the accelerated exponential (both expl).